# Jinja Templates - Format a float as comma-separated currency

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to format a float as comma-separated currency.  E.g. `543921.9354` becomes `$543,921.94`.  I'm using the `format` filter in Jinja templates, which seems to mimic the `%` operator in Python rather than the Python `format` function?

How can I accomplish this formatting in Jinja?  Is it possible using the `format` filter?  This is what I have so far, which accomplishes everything except the commas:

`"$%.2f"|format(543921.9354)`

which of course yields

`$543921.94`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Write a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters) for that. If you are using python 2.7, it can look like this:

```
def format_currency(value):
    return "${:,.2f}".format(value)
```

Answer (score 105):

Update:  Using Jinja2 and Python 3, this worked quite nicely in the template without having to define any custom code:

```
{{ "${:,.2f}".format(543921.9354) }}
```

I'm not sure exactly what the dependencies are to have this work, but IMHO anyone else reading this answer would do well to at least try it before worrying about custom filters.

Comment: This is working for me on Python 2.7 as well.  Great answer!

Comment: any idea on how to hide the round part and only display decimals?

Comment: Works Great!! One downside is for negative numbers the sign is after the $. Ex: -1000.50 = $-1,000.50. I was able to solve this by writing a custom filter using babel

Comment: Good point Ravishankar.  I don't have Jinja2 at my fingertips anymore but I wonder if something like this would work? 
{{ n >= 0 ? "${:,.2f}".format(n) : "-${:,.2f}".format(abs(n)) }}   Let us know if you can try it.  :)

Answer (score 14):

## Python3.6:

```
def numberFormat(value):
    return format(int(value), ',d')
```

## Flask global filter

```
@app.template_filter()
def numberFormat(value):
    return format(int(value), ',d')
```

## Flask global filter for Blueprint

```
@app.app_template_filter()
def numberFormat(value):
    return format(int(value), ',d')
```

## Call this global filter

```
{{ '1234567' | numberFormat }}
#prints 1,234,567
```

## Calling it in Jinja without assigning a global filter

```
{{ format('1234567', ',d') }}
#prints 1,234,567
```

Answer (score 7):

To extend @alex vasi's answer, I would definitely write a custom filter, but I'd also use python's own `locale` functionality, which handles currency grouping, and the symbol,

```
def format_currency(value):
    return locale.currency(value, symbol=True, grouping=True)
```

The main thing to take note of using `locale` is that it doesn't work with the default 'C' locale, so you have to set it so something that's available on your machine.

For what you're looking for, you probably need,

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
```

but if you wanted sterling pounds, you'd use,

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_GB.UTF_8')
```

.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
locale.currency(543921.94, symbol=True, grouping=True)
> '$543,921.94'
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_GB')
> '£543,921.94'
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you have Python 2.6 or newer:**

You could write a custom filter for one purpose, but, as a broader solution, you could also update the format filter itself:

```
from jinja import Environment, FileSystemLoader

def format(fmt_str, *args, **kwargs):
    if args and kwargs:
        raise jinja2.exceptions.FilterArgumentError(
            "can't handle positional and keyword "
            "arguments at the same time"
        )
    ufmt_str = jinja2.utils.soft_unicode(fmt_str)
    if kwargs:
        return ufmt_str.format(**kwargs)
    return ufmt_str.format(*args)


env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('./my/template/dir'))
env.filters.update({
    'format': format,
})
```

This will replace the existing `format` filter (as of Jinja 2.7.1). The majority of the function was ripped straight from the [`format`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/filters.py#L532) source. The only difference between this function and jinja's is that it uses the [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function to format the string.

Seeing that Jinja2 (at the time of this writing) no longer supports Python 2.5, I bet it won't be long before the `format` filter uses Python's [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Answer (score 3):

Custom Filter using Babel (Can be used to format other currencies as well)

Install Babel (http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html)

```
pip install Babel
```

Custom Jinja Filter

```
from babel.numbers import format_currency

@app.template_filter()
def usdollar(value):
   return format_currency(value, 'USD', locale='en_US')

app.jinja_env.filters['usdollar'] = usdollar
```

Usage in Jinja Template:

```
{{ '-10000.500' | usdollar }}

Output : -$10,000.50
```