# How to display large numbers with thousands separators with jinja?

Tags: python, css, jinja2

I work a lot with large numbers in tables and I would like to display the numbers this way:
"1 000 000" or "1,000,000" instead of "1000000". Is there a filter that allows this with jinja or css ?

I haven't found it in the documentation or on the internet except using javascript.

Comment: Not AFAIK in CSS. This [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677805/formatting-numbers-decimal-places-thousands-separators-etc-with-css#:~:text=Is%20it%20possible%20to%20format%20numbers%20with%20CSS%3F,for%20other%20number%20formats%2C%20e.g.%20latin%2C%20arabic%2C%20etc. shows a JS alternative.

Comment: Do any of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31158813/14316282) help?

Comment: No, I am looking for a solution with a jinja filter, without javascript.

Comment: check [this](https://code-maven.com/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separator) solution

Comment: I know this question is quite old, but in case you are wondering how you can do `{{ "{:,}".format(1000000) }}` where `1000000` can be your int variable.