# Currency format in flask jinja2 with both cents and commas

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to express an amount with both cents and commas. I can find the way to do this for the cents, but not both. Here is what I am using for cents.

```
{{"$%.2f"|format(price)}}
```

I have tried the following

```
{{"${:,.2f}"|format(price)}}
```

But this generates an error

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jinja Templates - Format a float as comma-separated currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078571/jinja-templates-format-a-float-as-comma-separated-currency)